# What is the difference of "Notification" and "Push Notification" in Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I want to use `Notification` in my Android app but I don't know what is the difference between `Notification` and `Push Notification` in Android.

I searched the web about this title but all of them talk about differences in apple products.

Can anyone remark where I should use `Notification` and where I should use `Push Notification`?

Comment: Notifications: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html "Push Notifications" via Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: @commonsWare thanks. a question: does push notification always show up as notification? or it can be shown as a toast or dialog box too?

Comment: "does push notification always show up as notification" -- if you are using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), there is no UI, except whatever UI you create in response to an incoming message.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that Push Notifications will show up on the device (phone's notifications or browser notifications) even if the app or website is NOT open, and normal notifications will show up only when the app is running / website is open in a tab ?

Answer (score 16):

The main difference between push notification and notification is that **the latter are created internally from an application on the device** that wants to show user some information, a reminder, some news or updates, and so on. **Push notification are "messages" sent from outside the device, for example a server, that triggers an application of the device** (which usually handle the incoming message and transform it in a "normal" notification to be displays in the system tray). This is usually made through a public service such as Firebase Cloud Message ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ ) of Google or a proprietary service such as the one that is used by the most common chatting application (Whatsapp, Telegram, ...) .

Indeed the most common example of push notification is the whatsapp notification of new messages that shows up in your phone when another user has sent you a message (so the message comes from outside your phone). Instead, the basic example for normal notifications are the alarm's notifications or the calendar's notifications.

Answer (score 7):

**Notification**: When notifies you about the same application state, example: In a game application: "You have 10 days trial, or a product that provides the application".

**Push Notification**: When notifies you in real time about events related to users, eg solical In an application, "A message from a friend, a new invitation, an event".