# Access Notifications from other apps on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am currently working with Unity's Mobile Notification Plugin and started wondering if it is possible to get infos of newly incoming Notifications on an Anroid Phone.

For example: While my Unity app is running, if there appears a new Notification from another app, is it possible to get the Text, Description, etc. of it?
When I tried it, I used this code here:

```
void Start()
{
    AndroidNotificationCenter.OnNotificationReceived += receivedNotificationHandler;
}

AndroidNotificationCenter.NotificationReceivedCallback receivedNotificationHandler =
delegate (AndroidNotificationIntentData data)
{     
    TMP_Text textBox = GameObject.Find("NotificationsInfo").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();

    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    .AppendLine("Notification received : " + data.Id)
    .AppendLine(" .Title: " + data.Notification.Title)
    .AppendLine(" .Body: " + data.Notification.Text)
    .Append(" .Channel: " + data.Channel);

    textBox.text = messageBuilder.ToString();
};
```

With that I was just able to get the infos of Notifications that were sent by the app itself but not from other apps. Is there a way to get the info from other apps as well?

Comment: You must have Usage Access for Notifications.. Did you handle that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two cases:

1. [Notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications) that are the ones on the top of Android bar and are created internally from an application on the device.
2. [Push Notification](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_push_notification.htm), that I think are the ones that you want.

More differences between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581302/what-is-the-difference-of-notification-and-push-notification-in-android).

If your case is the second one, which I think it is, I think that no, you cannot intercept push notifications from another app for security reasons.

If it's the first one, yes, you can create a plugin that calls native Android [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) and from there, manage the results, but be aware that you need to ask for user permision.

I think that Unity `AndroidNotificationCenter` only works for the unity app that is calling it.

Comment: My Goal is basically to make an App which checks for new Push notifications. (notifications for direct messages from Discord to be exact) I thought it may be possible to get the Notification details since they were displayed as any other Notification though I suppose I was wrong with that assumption. Thank you for the great explanation though!

Comment: Is it possible to get detail like exact message content of notification shown by the other app.

Answer (score 1):

I have used notification log apps which are available in playstore. Those apps are getting the notifications text and description and time etc and save them inside. If that's possible then, You could build something similar to that with help of it.

One of the repo of notification logger I found: https://github.com/interactionlab/android-notification-log

If possible you can analyse this and work around it to make the requirement.

I don't know this help or not, just wished to put it around. Sorry, if it doesn't